# JQuery: How to match the input value to all <td> elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to get all span texts and match to text input on jQuery?
This is my HTML Code. A table with a data and a span which contains texts `MEW`, `MEWL` and `MOWL`:

**My jQuery Code attempt. It always alerts `false`:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#txt').val == $('.answer').text()) {
      alert("true");
    } else {
      alert("false");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="answer">MEW</span></td>
    <td><span class="answer">MEWL</span></td>
    <td><span class="answer">MOWL</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />
```

I want to check the span's texts if it matches the input value , for example: I'll type MEW the system should alert true because MEW is present to the spans' text.

Comment: Probably because your `txt` property is not a `class`, but an `id`.

Comment: HI, put you span answer in <select> or gives Id's to your answer span, the class will fetch always the last answer.

Comment: I'm sorry that's just a typo. But it doesn't work also even I changed it.

Comment: $(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        $('table').find('td').each(function(){
          var ans = $(this).find('span').text();
          if($('#txt').val == ans){
            alert("true");
          }
          else{
            alert("false");
          }
        });        
    });
});

Comment: `val` is a function so use `val()`

Comment: @SanjayKumar It only alerts false 3 times.

Comment: please do as suggested by @Satpal

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        $('table').find('td').each(function(){
          var ans = $(this).find('span').text();
         
          if($('#txt').val() == ans){
            alert("true");
          }
          else{
            alert("false");
          }
        });        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="answer">MEW</span></td>
    <td><span class="answer">MEWL</span></td>
    <td><span class="answer">MOWL</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line will give you an array of texts from your span `.answer`.
`$('.answer').toArray().map(x => $(x).text())`

`.includes()` will check if array contains that value or not. It will return `true` or `false`.

You can check as below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {        
    if ($('.answer').toArray().map(x => $(x).text()).includes($('#txt').val())) {
      alert("true");
    } else {
      alert("false");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="answer">MEW</span></td>
    <td><span class="answer">MEWL</span></td>
    <td><span class="answer">MOWL</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$('#txt').val` should be `$('#txt').val()`, because its a method. Read More about [`.val()` here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

You need to iterate over the all `.answer` element and check whether the value is matched or not.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    var found = false;
    $('.answer').each(function(index, elem){
        if($(elem).text().toLowerCase().trim() == $('#txt').val().toLowerCase().trim()) {
        found = true;
        return false;
        }
   });
   alert(found);
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
    var found = false;
      $('.answer').each(function(index, elem){
        if($(elem).text().toLowerCase().trim() == $('#txt').val().toLowerCase().trim()) {
              found = true;
              return false;
        }
      });
      alert(found);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="answer">MEW</span></td>
        <td><span class="answer">MEWL</span></td>
        <td><span class="answer">MOWL</span></td>
    </tr> 
</table>

<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />
```